# Need to see only values written to CSV, seeing additional information

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping a website for values, i am successful in getting the values i need. But when i see console or csv file i am seeing additional information of datatype, name etc.

I would like to see only numbers ignoring all other additional information.

Response i would like to see

```
20MICRONS,75,153,2
21STCENMGM,42,52,8
360ONE,62,42,389
3IINFOLTD,1,165,35
3MINDIA,72,110,177
```

Response i am seeing:

```
0    75
Name: epsRank, dtype: int64
0    153
Name: industryGroupRank, dtype: object
0    2
Name: noOfFunds, dtype: int64
0    42
Name: epsRank, dtype: int64
0    58
Name: industryGroupRank, dtype: object
0    8
Name: noOfFunds, dtype: int64
0    62
Name: epsRank, dtype: int64
0    42
Name: industryGroupRank, dtype: object
0    389
Name: noOfFunds, dtype: int64
0    1
Name: epsRank, dtype: int64
0    165
Name: industryGroupRank, dtype: object
0    35
Name: noOfFunds, dtype: int64
0    72
Name: epsRank, dtype: int64
0    110
Name: industryGroupRank, dtype: object
0    177
Name: noOfFunds, dtype: int64
```

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jul 25 13:43:22 2023

@author: eruku
"""

import pandas as pd
import requests

infile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/WIP_Projects/Marketsmithindia/StocksList.txt'
outfile = 'C:/Volume/PythonProjects/WIP_Projects/Marketsmithindia/MktSmithData.csv'

timeout = 10
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}


# url = 'https://msi-gcloud-prod.appspot.com/gateway/simple-api/ms-india/instr/0/3023210/symboldetails.json?s=20180719&e=20230719&text=TVSSRICHAK&lang=en&isConsolidated=0&ms-auth=3990+MarketSmithINDUID-Web0000000000+MarketSmithINDUID-Web0000000000+0+230325200706+-514613229'
Part1 = 'https://msi-gcloud-prod.appspot.com/gateway/simple-api/ms-india/instr/0/'
Part2 = '/symboldetails.json?s=20180719&e=20230719&text='
Part3 = '&lang=en&isConsolidated=0&ms-auth=3990+MarketSmithINDUID-Web0000000000+MarketSmithINDUID-Web0000000000+0+230325200706+-514613229'
#MUID = '3023009'
#STOCK = 'ACCELYA'


with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open(outfile, 'w') as OUT:
    for DATA in IN:
        STOCK, MUID = DATA.split(',')
        # url = starturl + stock + endurl
        url = Part1 + MUID + Part2 + STOCK + Part3
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        df1 = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['response']['quarterlySalesAndEarningsInternational']['quarterlySalesAndEarningsOrigin'][0])
        # df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['response']['detailsGeneralInformationHeader'])
        df2 = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['response']['detailsGeneralInformationHeader'])
        GR = df2.loc[:,"industryGroupRank"]
        EPR = df2.loc[:,"epsRank"]
        Funds = df1.loc[:,"noOfFunds"]

        try:
            line = '%s,%s,%s,%s' % (
                STOCK,
                EPR,
                GR,
                Funds                
            )

            # df1.to_csv('MktSmithData.csv', index=False)
            print(EPR)
            print(GR)
            print(Funds)
            print(line, file=OUT)
        except KeyError as E:
            print(DATA, 'KeyError:', E)
```

StockList.txt

```
20MICRONS,3104964
21STCENMGM,3099129
360ONE,3161823
3IINFOLTD,3029382
3MINDIA,3023245
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're working with the data and selecting only one column at a time, resulting in a single-column Series, when what you want is to combine the columns into a single row and write it to a file. You can combine all the data into one row at the end of the loop and then write it to the file. Here is the modified code:

```
with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open(outfile, 'w') as OUT:
    for DATA in IN:
        STOCK, MUID = DATA.strip().split(',')  # Remove newline and split the data
        url = Part1 + MUID + Part2 + STOCK + Part3
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        df1 = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['response']['quarterlySalesAndEarningsInternational']['quarterlySalesAndEarningsOrigin'][0])
        df2 = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['response']['detailsGeneralInformationHeader'])
        GR = df2.loc[0, "industryGroupRank"]  # Select the value directly using loc
        EPR = df2.loc[0, "epsRank"]
        Funds = df1.loc[0, "noOfFunds"]

        try:
            line = '%s,%s,%s,%s' % (
                STOCK,
                EPR,
                GR,
                Funds
            )
            print(line, file=OUT)
        except KeyError as E:
            print(DATA, 'KeyError:', E)
```

**Use the .strip() method to remove line breaks from each line of data.

Use the .loc[0, ...] syntax to directly select specific cell values instead of entire columns.**

The results it grabs will look like the following

```
20MICRONS,75,153,2
21STCENMGM,42,58,8
360ONE,62,42,389
3IINFOLTD,1,165,35
3MINDIA,72,110,177
```